# How can pigs and shellfish be kosher for bnei Noach?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, slaughter-shochet-shecht, noachide-laws

As a ben Noach, I watch what meat I eat. I eat kosher or halal cut meat only. However, I think that bnei Noach aren't forbidden from eating pig meat or shellfish.

How would I make sure that such meat is kosher for bnei Noach? Would it be as simple as just making sure the limbs of the animal are intact upon slaughter?

Since bnei Noach food is mostly a superset of Jewish kashrut, I would think most kashrut and shechita laws pertain only to Jewish laws and that it wouldn't focus on bnei Noach shechita laws as much or at all(sadly).

I personally indirectly solve this by staying away from pig meat, but technically I would think I could consume pig meat. Same thing with shellfish, etc.

Comment: TTBOMK, you can eat any meat of any dead animal.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16649/are-there-any-hechshers-that-certify-food-as-kosher-for-bnei-noach

Comment: @dan that's a nice link, but it's not the same question as mine

Comment: i didn't mark it a duplicate, just a resource -- the answer provided makes a statement about what a B"N needs to be concerned about in terms of meat

Comment: Did you mean that BN food is a *superset* of kashrut? More is permitted to BN than to Jews.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I did! Thank you. Actually, come to think of it, some parts are exclusive concerning the living limb. I think a Jew can eat a limb in a certain condition, but I forget the condition. In other words, it's a superset except this one exception.

Comment: @EhevuTov The condition is between shechting and the end of the death rattle: kosher for Jews but not for non-Jews.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin My understanding is that not all standard meat plants are careful to cut the meat off the animal only after it has fully died.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, thank you! you guys are awesome.

Comment: If you don't know for sure that the meat is a detached limb, you have a doubt. I am not sure if we say that you need a double doubt for non-Jews (if I remember correctly, the whole concept of requiring a doubt in a Torah prohibition to be stringent was instituted by the rabbis, which would mean that it doesn't apply to non-Jews)

Comment: @ba That being stringent on a Torah prohibition was instituted by the rabbis is the opinion of the Rambam. Most rishonim (I think led by the Rashba) hold it is a built in Torah rule.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you for the names (by the way, [Meshech Chachmah on this parshah on the pasuk לא תסור](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14061&st=&pgnum=354) is especially relevant here)

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes it is a Torah rule in some cases (even according to the Rambam) or perhaps most cases, but does it apply to Sheva Mitzvos?

Comment: I'm not an expert in the Noachide Shulchan Aruch, but isn't Eiver Min HaChai only if you eat the part of the animal while it is still alive? Even if the part was cut off while the animal was still alive, it's dead now

Comment: Part of the information you are interested in is discussed in the Shulchan Aruch code of law (SA YD 27) and its commentaries.  According to Noahide law, one may not partake of an animal before that animal is dead.  Even when that animal subsequently dies, that part removed before death is forbidden.

Comment: An exception to that rule is when a one can piggy-back (no pun intended) on a Jewish permit. Since the Jewish permit for eating an animal is slaughter, not death, a kosher slaughtering would render the animal permitted and allow removal of a limb even before death (though as a technical rule, one may not eat it until the animal dies).The condition of this ruling is that the animal must be a kosher animal to which the laws of slaughtering apply, and the slaughtering must be done according to Jewish law.

Comment: Although Maimonides forbids the above for non-Jews, the Shach qualifies that he is referring to where the animal belonged to the non-Jew but was slaughtered according to Jewish law- the slaughtering permit would not apply to the non-Jew (he doesn't elaborate on the reasoning). **To sum up:**  The Noahide law of eating from a live animal would require one to have "knowledge" that the animal was dead before the removal of the meat.  The exception is a kosher animal slaughtered according to Jewish law. According to some, this animal (which nowadays usually means the processor) must be Jewish.

Comment: Couldn't you eat lobster, though?  Doesn't lobster need to be dead (by boiling) before it can be consumed?

Comment: One delicacy you have to stay away from are "Rocky Mountain Oysters," which are fried testicles of castrated cows and sheep -- which are still living.   Raw oysters are probably a problem, too, although some claim they die when ripped from their shells.  All of the above are disgusting IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

This is a great question that highlights the differences between the halachah for a ben Noach and the halachah for Am Yisrael.

I think that it is worthwhile to ask this question l'maaseh to a posek who has some familiarity with the laws for the bnei Noach but...

While it might seem that it is safest to purchase kosher meat to avoid any issue of *ever min haChai* (the prohibition against eating a limb from a living animal, the "*kashrus*" issue for *B'nei Noach*), it is not clear that this is automatically the case.  According to some authorities although a Jew is permitted to eat meat taken subsequent to the two *simanim* (signs) of *shechita* (slaughter) being severed, while it remains prohibited to a *ben Noach* as long as the animal moves (*Rambam* in the *Mishneh Torah*, *Hilchos Melachim* 9:12,13, the footnote in the Moznaim English translation explains that the *Rashba* and others rule that a non-Jew is not liable in the circumstance where a Jew isn't based on Hullin 121b).

Practically however, State and Federal laws in the United States regarding slaughter would prevent commercially produced meat from being taken while an animal is still alive. Although I'm not sure we can apply concepts such as *Rov* or *Chazakah*  in the framework of the *Sheva Mitzvos B'nei Noach*, nevertheless it seems to me reasonable that one can rely on the government in this situation insofar as they are effectively exercising their obligation to set up "court" which prevent taking an "*ever min haChai*". As such it would seem permissible for a B'nei Noach to purchase pork sold commercially in the stores. Furthermore the Rambam rules (*ibid* 10:1) that with the exception of murder a non-Jew is not liable for an inadvertent transgression (*b'shogaig*).

With regard to shellfish it would not seem to be a concern because it is not clear that the prohibition applies to fish at all. The Rambam understands the prohibition as not applying to poultry/fowl (ibid 9:11). Though the Rava'ad (see Moznaim *ibid*) disagrees, he exempts a *sheretz* (creeping creature), and it is would seem seafood is just out of the equation. Additionally shellfish are often sold live, whole, or effectively whole/clearly "slaughtered". If there is reason to be concerned about *ever min haChai* regarding seafood it shouldn't be difficult obtaining seafood whose suitability is evident.

Answer (score 0):

as a ben Noach, you don't need shchita. all you need is the animal completely dead. 
any way, you can't do shechita to a pig, simply because his anatomy is different. 
about shell fish, I think they are just fish, and there for you don't need to be shochet them even if you are jewish.

Comment: What aspect of the pig's anatomy would prevent one from slicing its throat?

Comment: I don't think shellfish are fish, but sheretz hayam.

Answer (score -3):

I actually would disagree that NO dietary laws are required for Bnei Noach, for as I read, the Torah states, "every living thing THAT MOVES...shall be food for you, etc."; therefore, there may be implied a prohibition against the consumption of true shell-fish, meaning those which live within actual shells, and are immobile, i.e. do not move; ex. mollusks (clams, oysters, mussels, avelone, etc.), and also see a clear prohibition against not simply the limb from a living animal(which I see no actual prohibition against, though it is clearly understood that this would be prohibited simply by reason of even the morality of the average Gentile), rather the prohibition is more akin to the tradition maintained by Halal of the Muslims, being the prohibition of eating red(living cells, filled with LIVING bacteria and viruses), un-drained, uncooked bloods.
 There are also deeper levels of interpretation that allude to the "food" of "supernal Torah", and the prohibition against "using for food", encapsulated parts of the Torah (shell-fish) as a means of spiritual nourishment. If one wishes to be "fit" for HaShem's Kingdom, one must "eat" from only those "living things" that may be found "moving" throughout the T"N"K" entire...i.e. one may not pick and choose from the parts one likes, removing them from their original context; and this applies to "foods" that "move" along the face of the ground, that is the clear, and literal reading of the Torah(Peshat), as well as those that one has to go "fishing" for, in the deep waters of the supernal Torah(Sod).

Answer (score -4):

There are only seven laws in the torah that non-jews (gentiles / benei noach) must follow . the rest ONLY apply to jews.

example : theft, murder..etc.

Comment: Ya, and one of them is Ever min haChai. Do you know if the shellfish are processed before they die?

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems you don't understand. If someone rips a piece of the animal off for packaging lets say before the animal dies, the piece remains forbidden even later. This can be an issue with larger mammals that the machines start taking the animal apart before it has stopped twitching. I assure you I know nothing of standard industrial shellfish packaging procedures, but if you do please inform me.

Comment: the typical procedure would be to kill them first, thus unless otherwise stated, we must assume that the responcibilities have been carried out correctly by the food providers. Furthermore, as long as you are not aware that it is a common practice by the suppling company to not comply with rules, you can eat all of their products. There is NO KOSHER laws for non jews, so eat all the pig and shellfish you like, as long as the animal is not breathing anymore

Comment: Do you mind my asking how you know so much about the industrial meat industry that we should trust you? (After that we can discuss how you know bittul berov applies to non Jews.)

Comment: I do IT for multiple large scale food industries and at times venture through their processessing plants. Does that qualify?

Comment: If that's the truth then so be it because what could possibly incentivize you to lie to us? You don't seem petty enough to lie like that for rep points. Odd though that the website in your profile seems to have nothing to do with that sector.

Comment: I have many websites, There is only link for one. Try JudaicWorld.com or JewsNY.com --just for kicks

Comment: um.  those websites are both nearly blank.... JudaicWorld.com has a title tag that says "Tag, youre it".  JewsNY.com is offline.  Neither seem to have anything to do with treif meat processing.

Comment: Am I reading your answer wrong? "_the rest ONLY apply to jews. example : theft, murder..etc._" are examples that apply only to Jews? ....theft and murder are two of the 7, so it would make sense that this last sentence modifies the first....am I right?

Comment: no, the example is for the first sentance as some of the 7 laws of noah