# What do Jews believe happens to Christians when they die?

Tags: death, christianity

I've been reading a lot about Judaism and Christianity lately, and how people say they're completely incompatible, so my question is, given the differences between them, what do Jews think happen to Christians when they die (hope the question isn't seen as offensive to anyone)?

Comment: It is a duplicate, I apologize. I wasn't really sure how to search for an answer since I'm unfamiliar with the Jewish terms of Heaven/Hell. So, according to Jewish belief, you can't eat meat and go to Heaven (that's what i read one of the 7 laws are).

Comment: Where did you read that one of the 7 laws are that meat is forbidden?

Comment: jewishvirtuallibrary, chabad, wikipedia, and aish, they all say you aren't to eat of a live animal (which sounds very much like you can't eat meat). Maybe I'm interpreting it incorrectly.

Comment: Meat from a still living animal is different from meat from a dead animal. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38217/difference-between-eiver-min-hachai-for-jews-and-noahides

Comment: Jmd82, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! No need to apologize for posting a duplicate; if you couldn't find the information you were looking for through intuitive search, then there are others out there who want the same information and would have similar difficulty. Thanks you your question, people who google for this information using similar words will be more likely to find it. Thanks for making the Internet richer! I hope you'll look around and find other information of interest, perhaps starting with some of our hundreds of [tag:gentiles] Q&As.

Comment: Thanks Isaac Moses & Danno, appreciate the links and kind words. I was also wondering, how come Jewish people won't type God, but instead type G-d?

Comment: Jmd82, feel free to post whatever questions you have as new question posts. As it happens, this one has been addressed here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36675/why-are-jews-so-meticulous-about-not-saying-writing-god

Comment: @Jmd82 see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83/when-blogging-emailing-etc-do-i-use-god-or-g-d?s=1|1.6617