# Does brain death count as death for animals and ever min hachai

Tags: halacha, animals, noachide-laws, yoreh-deah, evar-min-hachai

According to Halacha, is Brain death in animals considered death for the purposes of Ever Min hachai? So could a brain dead animal have its limb removed and eaten for noahides? Obviously Jews have to have shechita but since non Jews don’t is brain death enough for it to be kosher for them?

Comment: For gentiles, an animal is still considered alive after shechita until it stops twitching. This is probably analogous.

Comment: How does one check an animal for brain death?

Comment: "Brain dead" is not a precise term, it doesn't mean that the brain is dead but rather it is not optimally functioning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no consideration for brain death for the purposes of ever min ha chai. The animal must be completely dead. No movement or cardiac function.

[Yoreh Deah 27](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.27.1?lang=bi)

> If one cuts from an animal a piece of meat after it was slaughtered properly and it is still twitching it is forbidden to eat from it before it (the animal) dies.

If the shechita wasn't kosher, this meat is not permitted to Noahides because it was taken from an animal that still showed the signs of life. Regardless of whether he waited until the animal died before eating it.  This is a rare case where Noahide law is more - not less - prohibitive than Jewish law.

[Hilchos Melachim 9:12,13](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188354/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-9.htm)

> 12 Though one slaughters an animal, even if one severs the two signs that distinguish it as having been slaughtered in a kosher manner, as long as the animal moves convulsively, the limbs and meat which are separated from it are forbidden to a Noachide because of the prohibition against a limb from a living creature.

> 13 All prohibitions that apply to a Jew regarding a limb from a living creature also apply to Noachides. Furthermore, there are instances where a Noachide would be held liable and a Jew will not for a Noachide is liable for a limb or flesh from a living creature whether from a domesticated animal or a beast, whether from a kosher or non-kosher species.
> Similarly, a Noachide is forbidden to partake of a limb from a living creature for a limb or flesh which is separated from an animal that is moving convulsively even though a Jew has already severed the two signs.

See also [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38217/difference-between-eiver-min-hachai-for-jews-and-noahides?rq=1) related question.