# Non Jews checking vegetables

Tags: halacha, gentiles, noachide-laws, bugs, inspection

Does a non-Jew need to check their lettuce for infestation. The thrips and other insects there may very well be alive. Would that violate "aver min hachai"?

Comment: related or duplicate of [Can a non-Jew eat living ants?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29825/11501)